# How to get the value of a datepicker using framework7 and vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, html-framework-7

I have the following component:

```
<f7-list-input
label=“Fecha de nacimiento”
type=“datepicker”
placeholder=“Selecciona una fecha”
:value=“perfil.fecha_nacimiento”
@input=“perfil.fecha_nacimiento = $event.target.value”
:calendar-params=“parametrosCalendario”
>

<f7-button class=“button button-big button-fill”
@click=“editarPerfil(perfil)”>Guardar   </f7-button>
```

script:

```
 data(){
            return {
                perfil: {
                    fecha_nacimiento: ''
                },
    },
   methods:{
    editarPerfil(perfil){
            let vm = this;
            console.log(perfil); //When printing in console, profile, birthdate, this gap.

        },
}
```

but when I get the information of the birthdate, I can not get it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it by javascript:

```
var calendar = app.calendar.get(element_selector); // Get the calendar instance
var values = calendar.getValue();   //Returns current calendar value
```

You can also find it in the official documentations:
[Framework7 calendar docs](https://framework7.io/docs/calendar.html)